# Port 8080 not accessible on Linux server

Tags: php, linux

I started local server using php on my server . (Trying to work on port 8080/8283 . Anyone of them will do .)

```
php -S 0.0.0.0 8283 -t testServer/
```

using `curl localhost:8283` I am able to get the result of the `index.php` file

but when I access it using my server ip I am not able to access that port .

Any when I do `netstat -tuplen` . I can see that port as well .

**How can I make port 8283 available through http request ?**

I asked this question here but not much help .

I have used this

```
# /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8283 -j ACCEPT
# service iptables save
# service iptables restart
```

and still it did not work

**And this is output from telnet on my server**

```
telnet XX.XX.X.XXX 8283
Trying XX.XX.X.XXX...
Connected to XX.XX.X.XXX.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /

HTTP/0.9 200 OK
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19
Content-type: text/html

Hello World !Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**this one is from my PC**

```
telnet XX.XX.X.XXX 8283
Trying XX.XX.X.XXX...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

**NMAP Result**

```
sudo nmap -p 8283 XX.XX.X.XXX

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-04 19:18 IST
Nmap scan report for srv1.domain.com (XX.XX.X.XXX)
Host is up (0.035s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8283/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.37 seconds
```

**IPTABLES OUTPUT**

```
/sbin/iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8282 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8283 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
php -S 0.0.0.0 8080 -t testServer/
```

by use `localhost` you will bound just `127.0.0.1` address: that address is not reachable by other address instead of `localhost` or `localhost.localdomin`.

Now by use `0.0.0.0` you will bound all your interfaces. Alternatively  you can use your host address where you want expose the service.

Comment: php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t testServer/ 

By using this I am able to access through SERVERIP:8080 through curl . But still I am not able to access it using webbrowser directly .

http://SERVERIP:8080/ does not work

Comment: http://SERVERIP:8080 in your browser address bar. Browser assume http just for 80 ports

Comment: @yantrakaar maybe in `/etc/services/` you will found a line like `http     2222/tcp` that map `2222` port in http service

Comment: @yantrakaar Sorry I noted that what I wrote was interpreted as link by wiki engine: put `http://SERVERIP:8080` in your browser bar.

Comment: Yes that does not work . However when I did cat /etc/services grep 8080 I got . webcache 8080/tcp   # WWW caching service
webcache 8080/udp   # WWW caching service

so does that mean it is used by other service ?

Comment: @yantrakar Yes, try to change port

Comment: I tried port 8283 now . It was not listed in /etc/services . It does not work as well .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70220/discussion-between-michele-damico-and-yantrakaar).

Comment: @yantrakaar Maybe it is more simple.... Can you post EXACTLY what do you write on chrome bar?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use localhost you have to use your external ip address:

```
php -S <ip-address> 8080 -t testServer/
```

localhost is mapped on ip `127.0.0.1` so it is only available from yor server.

Comment: Do you get a `404` error or what does "not accessible" means ?

Comment: " This webpage is not available " in chrome

Comment: Is it possible that I cannot access port 8080 from outside my server ?

Comment: @yantrakaar Proxy or firewall problems?

Comment: sorry but I am not aware on how to check that on server . Any idea on how can I confirm ?

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      58        27927871 2149/php

Comment: @yantrakaar can you try it from your server using `telnet serverip 8080`?

Comment: What is your serverip?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70213/discussion-between-yantrakaar-and-jens).

Answer (score -1):

You're explicitly binding to `localhost`. If you want to bind to a different IP address, then specify it instead of `localhost` (or use `0.0.0.0` for all network interfaces).